# How to start opcua server?

Tags: go, opc-ua

Hey I downloaded the following OPC implementation with golang https://github.com/gopcua/opcua, but I can't figure out how to run the tests without running the server! I am using go version `go1.15.2 linux/amd64`
for example when running this:

```
go run server.go
```

I get the following response:

```
go run: cannot run non-main package
```

Either the doc doesn't explain how to start the server, someone can help pls ?

Comment: `go run examples/server/server.go`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dave, I get the following error:
```# github.com/gopcua/opcua/ua
ua/enums_gen.go:10:8: imported and not used: "time"
ua/extension_object.go:119:8: undefined: AnonymousIdentityToken
ua/extension_object.go:121:8: undefined: UserNameIdentityToken
ua/extension_object.go:123:8: undefined: X509IdentityToken
ua/extension_object.go:125:8: undefined: IssuedIdentityToken
ua/extension_object.go:127:8: undefined: ServerStatusDataType
ua/request_header.go:37:10: undefined: RequestHeader```